# Yii2 ActiveRecord sorting by translatable field

Tags: php, yii2

I have a table in my database with a `name` field which content I want to translate. I am using [lajax/translate-manager](https://github.com/lajax/yii2-translate-manager) for that, and it's working fine. The problem comes when I want to sort the data in a GridView (or some other widget) by `name`. When I query the database I specify `name` as the sorting field, but it is done in the language it is stored (English). Then I use the `Yii::t()` function in the GridView column to output the field and it gets translated, but obviously the ordering remains the same.

For example, in the table profession I have a row for which `name` takes the value `Accounting`, that in Spanish is `Contabilidad`. If I show the table in Spanish that row should appear below than in English, and that is not happening.

**Solution:** I ended up fetching all records from the database as array, translating them with Yii::t and then putting it into an [ArrayDataProvider](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-arraydataprovider.html). One more thing: to allow filtering I had also to check the correspondent columns of the array with PHP's function [fnmatch](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fnmatch.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want translate `Accounting` on the fly in mysql request. It's not work.

You have two ways:

- Create at table field `name_spanish` and make sort by this field in mysql.
- Fetch all records, translate values by `Yii::t()` and perform sorting in php.